# spring boot thymeleaf unexpected different rendering for different @GetMapping paths

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm currently playing with [spring-boot-bootstrap-thymeleaf-tree-table](https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/spring-boot-bootstrap-thymeleaf-tree-table)
I was migrating the code into my spring-boot project and anything went well.
But if i change the @GetMapping path to pass a @PathVariable to the thymeleaf page the rendering changed.

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class NodesController {
    
    @GetMapping("/user/object/{identifier}")
    public String nodes(@PathVariable String identifier, Model model) {
        return "objectDetails";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/nodes")
    public String nodes2(Model model) {
        return "objectDetails";
    }    
}
```

Both mappings/methods are using the same template. But the 'nodes2' works well, 'nodes' not.

**Expected result with 'nodes2' Path: @GetMapping("/nodes")**

[image: expected]

**Broken result with 'nodes' Path: @GetMapping("/user/object/{identifier}")**

[image: broken]

**Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Object details</title>
    <th:block th:include="head :: head"/>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.css}"/>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.theme.default.css}"/>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-2/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="menu :: menu"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col mt-5">

            <table id="treeTable" class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Predicate</th>
                    <th>Object</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.js}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            "type": 'get',
            "url": '/tree/9d317daca74246d4be41b1a37e30ee2a',
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
                    $("#treeTable").append("<tr data-tt-id=\"" + obj.nodeId + "\" data-tt-parent-id=\"" + obj.parent + "\"><td>" + obj.subjectShort + "</td><td>" + obj.predicate + "</td><td>" + obj.object + "</td></tr>");
                });
                $("#treeTable").treetable({
                    expandable: true,
                    initialState: "expanded",
                    clickableNodeNames: true,
                    indent: 30
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the incorrectly rendered page, are there any "404 not found" errors (see your browser console's network tab) relating to your CSS or JS resources? Or any other errors in the main browser console?

Comment: Great hint !!
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/user/object/assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.theme.default.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the GetMapping, the path for loading js resources is changing!

```
localhost:8080/user/object/assets/
```

instead of

```
localhost:8080/assets/
```

**Resolved by changing the link from:**

```
<link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.css}"/>
```

to:

```
<link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../../assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.css}"/>
```

thanks @andrewJames for the hint !

Comment: Glad you solved it. What about using `th:href="@{/assets/jquery-treetable/jquery.treetable.css}"` - with an initial `/`? (I have not tested this - just a suggestion). See [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for an overview of the different types of Thymeleaf URL formats.